# Can't connect to container cluster: environment variable HOME or KUBECONFIG must be set when running gcloud get credentials

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

For some reason I can't connect to the cluster. Having followed the instructions per google container-engine after setting up the cluster, I get the following error:

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) environment variable HOME or KUBECONFIG must be set to store credentials for kubectl

When running this command:  gcloud container clusters get-credentials [my cluster name] --zone us-central1-b --project [my project name]

Any ideas how I should be setting the variable HOME or KUBECONFIG. I couldn't find anything specific for container-engine.

Comment: Did you get it on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it working:

In Windows, you should set environment variable:
[image]

and then creating a folder and a file under current user folder, as the following:

```
mkdir .kube
cd .kube
echo "" > config
```

As you make the config file under current user, gcloud should have the right permissions to access the file.

Answer (score 4):

gcloud attempts to write a kubeconfig file to `$HOME/.kube/config` (or `$KUBECONFIG` if it is set). The most straightforward approach is to set `HOME` to your home directory, but if you have a reason that you'd like to store your kubectl configuration elsewhere, you can do that with the `KUBECONFIG` variable.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes it bit clearer. I was overthinking it, expecting it to maybe  need some kind of credential file in there, but It seems obvious now it's just trying to set it, and needs to know where.