# Issue in setting up KUBECTL on Windows 10 Home

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to learn Kubernetes and so I installed Minikube on my local Windows 10 Home machine and then I tried installing the kubectl. However so far I have been unsuccessful in getting it right.
So this what I have done so far:
Downloaded the kubectl.exe file from https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.18.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe

Then I added the path of this exe in the `path environment variable` as shown below:
[image]

However this didn't work when I executed `kubectl version` on the command prompt or even on pwoershell (in admin mode)

Next I tried using the curl command as given in the docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-windows

However that too didn't work as shown below:
[image]

Upon searching for answers to fix the issue, I stumbled upon this [StackOverfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922430/cant-connect-to-container-cluster-environment-variable-home-or-kubeconfig-must) which explained how to create a `.kube` config folder because it didn't exist on my local machine. I followed the instructions, but that too failed.

[image]
[image]

So right now I am completely out of ideas and not sure whats the issue here. FYI, I was able to install everything in a breeze on my Mac, however Windows is just acting crazy.

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: did you do a `minikube start` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user @paltaa mentioned:

> did you do a  `minikube start`  ? – [paltaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6855531/paltaa)  [2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144233/issue-in-setting-up-kubectl-on-windows-10-home#comment108172290_61144233)

**The fact that you did not start the `minikube` is the most probable cause why you are getting this error.**

---

Additionally this error message shows when the `minikube` is stopped as stopping will change the `current-context` inside the `config` file.

---

There is no need to create a `config` file inside of a `.kube` directory  as the `minikube start` will create appropriate files and directories for you automatically.

If you run `minikube start` command successfully you should get below message at the end of configuration process which will indicate that the `kubectl` is set for `minikube` automatically.

> Done! kubectl is not configured to use "minikube"

Additionally if you invoke command `$ kubectl config` you will get more information how `kubectl` is looking for configuration files:

```
 The loading order follows these rules:

  1.  If the --kubeconfig flag is set, then only that file is loaded. The flag may only be set once and no merging takes
place.
  2.  If $KUBECONFIG environment variable is set, then it is used as a list of paths (normal path delimiting rules for
your system). These paths are merged. When a value is modified, it is modified in the file that defines the stanza. When
a value is created, it is created in the first file that exists. If no files in the chain exist, then it creates the
last file in the list.
  3.  Otherwise, ${HOME}/.kube/config is used and no merging takes place.
```

Please take a special look on part:

> 3. Otherwise, ${HOME}/.kube/config is used

Even if you do not set the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable `kubectl` will default to `$USER_DIRECTORY` (for example `C:\Users\yoda\`.

If for some reason your cluster is running and files got deleted/corrupted you can:

- `minikube stop`
- `minikube start`

which will recreate a `.kube/config`

---

Steps for running `minikube` on Windows in this case could be:

- Download and install [Kubernetes.io: Install minikube using an installer executable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/#install-minikube-using-an-installer-executable)
- Download, install and configure a Hypervisor (for example [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/))
- Download [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)

  - OPTIONAL: Add the `kubectl` directory to Windows environment variables
- Run from command line or powershell from current user: `$ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`
- Wait for configuration to finish and invoke command like `$ kubectl get nodes`.

Comment: minikube stop
minikube start  fixed my Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.17.241.253:8443: